# Red box isn't placed as expected

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute

I tried to do this in code pen

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="red">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="blue">

  </div>

<div class="yellow">

  </div>

</body>



CSS


body{

  margin:0;

}

.container{

  postion:relative;

  height:300px;

  width:300px;

  background-color:green;

}

.red{

  height:100px;

  width:100px;

  background-color:red;

  display:inline-block;

  position:absolute;

  right:20px;

}

.blue{

  height:100px;

  width:100px;

  background-color:blue;

  display:inline-block;

  position:absolute;

  top:100px;

  left:100px;

}

.yellow{

  height:100px;

  width:100px;

  background-color:yellow;

  display:inline-block;

  position:absolute;

  top:0;

}
```

And this is what my preview looks like

[image]

The red box even though its parent is the div with class name container isn't placed 20px to the right with respect to the right side of the green box.

Why is that so?

Comment: Can you share the pen link it would be easy to help then

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: You would like to place the red box on top right corner of the green box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error `postion:relative;` to `position:relative;`

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:green;

}
```

```css
body{

  margin:0;

}

.container{

  position:relative;

  height:300px;

  width:300px;

  background-color:green;

}

.red{

  height:100px;

  width:100px;

  background-color:red;

  display:inline-block;

  position:absolute;

  right:20px;

}

.blue{

  height:100px;

  width:100px;

  background-color:blue;

  display:inline-block;

  position:absolute;

  top:100px;

  left:100px;

}

.yellow{

  height:100px;

  width:100px;

  background-color:yellow;

  display:inline-block;

  position:absolute;

  top:0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="red">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="blue">

  </div>

<div class="yellow">

  </div>
```